# How to filter the string/array by using java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need a help on below questions. As per the code im getting the below output:

```
parameter_Name: Raghu
parameter_Name: Kartik
parameter_Name: sundar
```

But in the content if i have the below format,

```
content = "Hi {{Raghu}}, this is your {{kartik}} last 4 {{sundar}}. {{each numberdetail}} {{loop_var. ABC}} {{loop_var. DEF}} {{loop_var. GHI}}{{end}}";
```

So in the above string, if {{each comes, will filter the "{{each" and will take "numberdetail" as seperate array. And if {{loop_var comes,remove loop_var and add ABC in numbderdetail error. If we find {{end}} then we will terminate the array.

Any idea please.

Expected Output:

```
"Parameter_name": "Raghu",
    "Salary": "32.17",
    "LineDetail": [{
        "ABC": "0",
        "DEF": "Device",
        "GHI": "792.00"
    }]
```

Code:

```
public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String content = "Hi {{Raghu}}, this is your {{kartik}} last 4 {{sundar}}.";

        String[] contentArray;
        List contentArrayList = new ArrayList();

        if (content != null && content.trim() != "" && !content.equals("")) {
            contentArray = content.split(" ");
            for (String out : contentArray) {
                if (!"".equals(out) && out.contains("{{")) {
                    String parameter_Name = out.substring(out.indexOf("{{") + 2, out.indexOf("}}"));
                    System.out.println("parameter_Name::" + parameter_Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say `content` is one thing at first but in your code, `content` does not match the description of what you said it was.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: I don't see you even trying to handle "{{each..." or "{{loop_var..." or "{{end}}" according to your described rules. What have you *tried*?

Comment: The main error here is your split, you are spliting by a space character and that's not right for your content

I think I would use a Pattern a matcher to extract all the variables and then you can work with them as you want.

Some clue:

 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{\\w+\\.* *\\w*\\}\\}");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(content);


List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (m.find( )) {
            list.add(m.group().replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", ""));
        }

Comment: Your question is quite unclear for me. 1. In your `content` string, I couldn't see the values like 32.17, 0, "Device" and 792.00 which you have mentioned for `salary`, `ABC`, `DEF` and `GHI`. Will these values be same for all the people?  2. Do you want to display the output like you have shown for every name encountered within `{{}}`?

Comment: Actually i gave sample example in the Content string. Assume that im having big textarea box and lot of {{ curly braces code was there. 
As per the above content string, I want to validate all the double Curly braces. If it {{ only available we will put this in one array(this is normal array). If {{each starts followed by anyword(numberdetail) then it will search {{loop_var(child value). If string found {{end}} then it will terminate the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think this is what you need.

```
public class JavaTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String content = "Hi {{Raghu}}, this is your {{kartik}} last 4 {{sundar}}. {{each numberdetail}} {{loop_var. ABC}} {{loop_var. DEF}} {{loop_var. GHI}}{{end}}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{\\w+\\.* *\\w*\\}\\}");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(content);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (m.find( )) {

        list.add(m.group().replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", ""));
    }

    boolean insideLoop= false;

    for (String current: list){

        if (current.startsWith("each")){
            insideLoop = true;
            System.out.println("Parameter_Name: " + current.split(" ")[1] + ": [{");

        } else if (insideLoop){
            if (current.startsWith("loop_var.")){
                String value = current.split(" ")[1];
                System.out.println("\"" + value + "\"");

            }else {
                if (current.startsWith("end")){
                    insideLoop = false;
                    System.out.println("}]");
                }
            }
        }else {
           System.out.println("Parameter_Name: " + current);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Output is:

```
Parameter_Name: Raghu
Parameter_Name: kartik
Parameter_Name: sundar
Parameter_Name: numberdetail: [{
"ABC"
"DEF"
"GHI"
}]
```

Comment: Hi Actually im looking the code for the below output: "Parameter_name": "2-3",
        "Salary": "32.17",
        "LineDetail": [{
            "ABC": "0",
            "DEF": "Device",
            "GHI": "792.00"
        }]

Comment: Hi Nancy

You've modified your question after i've posted my answer. I still think my answer can give you an almost complete clue to start.

Comment: @scouto- Actually i gave sample output in content string. But keep in mind that, From the String content, Number of lines will be more. But all these values are printing by using Syste,.out.prntln. I want all these values in JSON object. kindly give me solution for this one. Kindly help me to resolve this. Im totally new for this java technology